# Clouser of the set of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $a_n$ be a sequence convergent to $q$ in $\bar U$ where $U$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb R^m$. Let $B=\{a_n; n\in \mathbb N\}$. Why is $\bar B=B\cup\{q\}$ if $q$ in the boundary of $U$ and $\bar B=B$ when $q\in U $?

Comment: That looks false to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is false.  At least part of it.

For any convergent sequence $\{a_n\}$ with limit $q$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if we let $B=\{a_n; n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $\overline{B}=B\bigcup\{q\}$, regardless of whether or not it is on the boundary of an open set (every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is on the boundary of some open set).

However, your second conclusion is false. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$, put $U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|x\|<1\}$, define the sequence $\{a_n\}$ by
$$a_n=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\0
\end{pmatrix},$$
and put
$$q=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\\0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then clearly $a_n\rightarrow q$ as $n\to\infty$ and $q\in U$. But $q\neq a_n$ for all $n$, thus $\overline{B}=B\bigcup\{q\}$ with $q\notin B$, so $\overline{B}\neq B$.

Comment: the proof of Lemma 1.4.7 is confusing me though, can you see where is the problem ? https://books.google.ca/books?id=x-wfDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&dq=Then+f+is+proper+if+and+only+if+for+every+sequence+%7Bp,)+in+U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAn9z7ypLOAhWmpYMKHWw2D1MQ6wEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Then%20f%20is%20proper%20if%20and%20only%20if%20for%20every%20sequence%20%7Bp%2C)%20in%20U&f=false

Comment: Which part is confusing you?

Comment: the first part of the proof

Comment: I see now.  Let's use the notation in the book. The proof is referring to $E$ as a *subspace* of $V$ (so we disregard the rest of $\mathbb{R}^m$).  If $q\in V$, then $\overline{E}=E\cup\{\textrm{all limit points of }E\}=E\cup\{q\}$.  But if $q\in\overline{V}$, then the sequence has no limit in $V$, and the closure of $E$ (again, as a subspace of $V$) is just itself.  Does that help?

Comment: yes, thank you :)

Comment: @Ronald Glad to help!